# Count Full Year from Date String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm currently working in Node with mongoose as a database. I have two models product and customer .whenever a customer buy a product, the current Date gets stored in **SellingDate** attribute of the product. Now the thing I want to achieve is that when we give a random Date as input, it should compare it with all Selling dates of all products up to one year, and return us COUNT OF ALL DATES THAT LIE BETWEEN ONE YEAR. **For example ,** if we have **5 records** in database **i.e**
{
**"Sun Feb 25 2015"** , "Fri Mar 25 2015" , "Sat Dec 25 2015" , **"Mon Feb 25 2016"**
}
and I give **" Sun Feb 25, 2015"** as input it should return 2 as output because we have two dates between **Feb 2015 - Feb 2016** .... and it should compare dates in **String** format because I store the date in **"Day Month Date Year"** format ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do an aggregation where you first convert the date strings to a date using `$toDate` and also keep track of the year using `$year`. Then you can `$match` all documents within the given date range, and finally `$group` by the year and `$count`:

```
YourModel.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
       "year":{ "$year": {
            "$toDate": "$date"
        }
    } }},
    {
        $match: {
            // define your range of years here, it would be 2015 - 2016 in your case
            year: {$gte: 2016, $lte: 2020}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {year: "$year"}
        }
    },
     {
      $count: "totalCountPerYearRange"
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the date strings are in an array - using [] NOT {} (which defines an object that requires property:value pairs), then you can convert the strings into dates and do simple comparisons.  The following will return an array, where you can simply get the array's length for the count.

```js
let myDates = [
    "Thu Jan 07 2016",
    "Tue Mar 01 2016",
    "Wed May 25 2016",
    "Sat Jun 25 2016",
    "Sun Aug 14 2016",
    "Fri Nov 18 2016",
    "Fri Jan 06 2017",
    "Sun Apr 16 2017",
    "Sun May 21 2017",
    "Sun Jul 30 2017",
    "Fri Sep 22 2017",
    "Sun Nov 12 2017",
    "Sun Dec 24 2017"
]

let firstDate = new Date("Wed May 25 2016");
let lastDate = new Date("Thu May 25 2017");

let matches = myDates.filter(d => {if (new Date(d) >= firstDate && new Date(d) <= lastDate) return d});
console.log(matches);
console.log(matches.length);
```

Comment: thanks alot , it really help ... appreciate your time